# How do I Merge these two VBA Codes

Tags: excel, vba, loops

Hi I am new to VBA code so far I have made this code which does what I need it to do for one row.

```
Sub Preliminaryworks()
    Dim ProjectManager_DayRate40 As Double
    Dim SiteManager_DayRate_80 As Double
    Dim OMManualPackage_ICP_Connection66kV_132kV As Double
    Dim OMManualsHardcopies3SetsofA4Foldersand1DVDelectroniccopy As Double
    Dim AdminAssistant_Day_rate As Double
    Dim Preliminaryworks As Double
    Dim SiteSetup As Double
    Dim ContestableDesignPackage As Double
    Dim Single132kVcircuitandpilot_fibre_trench_Ducted_Agricultural_250 As Double
    Dim Single132kVcircuitandpilot_fibre_trench_Ducted_Road_250 As Double
    Dim Single132kVcircuitandpilot_fibretrench_Ducted_Verge As Double
    Dim Single132kVcircuitandpilotfibre_trench_Ducted_Footpath_250 As Double
    Dim Cable132kVforateedconnection300Cu As Double
    Dim cable132kVforaloopedconnection1000Cu As Double
    Dim Stokboard1m_overlapped275 As Double
    Dim Terminationkitsatthe132kVsealingends_setof3_1 As Double
    Dim Fibreopticcableandinstallation270 As Double
    Dim Ducting110mmPilotspermetre250 As Double
    Dim JointBay_132kVsinglecircuitandpilot_fibre_Agricultural As Double
    Dim JointBay_132kVsinglecircuitandpilot_fibre_Road As Double
    Dim JointBay_132kVsinglecircuitandpilot_fibre_verge As Double
    Dim JointBayatPOC_132kVsinglecircuitandpilo_fibre_Ducted_Footpath As Double
    Dim Tiletape150mmX250mWPDspec1  As Double
    Dim CableInstallationTeam_4men_1x_Supervisorand3xlabourers_DayRate As Double
    Dim JointingTeam_1xJointer1xMate_DayRate4  As Double
    Dim CableRoute132_66kV As Double
    Dim sumof132kVPOCtoPOSUndergroundCableRoute As Double
    Dim sumof33kVPOStoSolarParkUndergroundCableRoute_metres As Double
    Dim Single132kVcircuitandpilot_fibre_trench_Ducted_Agricultural_2501 As Double
    Dim Single132kVcircuitandpilot_fibre_trench_Ducted_Road_2501 As Double
    Dim Single132kVcircuitandpilot_fibretrench_Ducted_Verge1 As Double
    Dim Single132kVcircuitandpilotfibre_trench_Ducted_Footpath_2501 As Double
    
    ' start of sumof132kVPOCtoPOSUndergroundCableRoute
    Dim sumof132kVPOCtoPOSUndergroundCableRouterng As Range
    Dim sumof132kVPOCtoPOSUndergroundCableRoutecell As Range
    
    ' Set the range to be summed
    Set sumof132kVPOCtoPOSUndergroundCableRouterng = Range("X3:AA3")
    
    ' Initialize the sum variable
    sumof132kVPOCtoPOSUndergroundCableRoute = 0
    
    ' Iterate through each cell in the range and add its value to the sum
    For Each sumof132kVPOCtoPOSUndergroundCableRoutecell In sumof132kVPOCtoPOSUndergroundCableRouterng
        sumof132kVPOCtoPOSUndergroundCableRoute = sumof132kVPOCtoPOSUndergroundCableRoute + sumof132kVPOCtoPOSUndergroundCableRoutecell.Value
    Next sumof132kVPOCtoPOSUndergroundCableRoutecell
    
    ' Assign the sum value to cell AT10
    Range("AT10").Value = sumof132kVPOCtoPOSUndergroundCableRoute
    ' End of sumof132kVPOCtoPOSUndergroundCableRoute
    
        ' start of 33kVPOStoSolarParkUndergroundCableRoute_metres
    Dim sumof33kVPOStoSolarParkUndergroundCableRoute_metresrng As Range
    Dim sumof33kVPOStoSolarParkUndergroundCableRoute_metrescell As Range
    
    ' Set the range to be summed
    Set sumof33kVPOStoSolarParkUndergroundCableRoute_metresrng = Range("AB3:AE3")
    
    ' Initialize the sum variable
    sumof33kVPOStoSolarParkUndergroundCableRoute_metres = 0
    
    ' Iterate through each cell in the range and add its value to the sum
    For Each sumof33kVPOStoSolarParkUndergroundCableRoute_metrescell In sumof33kVPOStoSolarParkUndergroundCableRoute_metresrng
        sumof33kVPOStoSolarParkUndergroundCableRoute_metres = sumof33kVPOStoSolarParkUndergroundCableRoute_metres + sumof33kVPOStoSolarParkUndergroundCableRoute_metrescell.Value
    Next sumof33kVPOStoSolarParkUndergroundCableRoute_metrescell
    
    ' Assign the sum value to cell AT10
    Range("AT11").Value = sumof33kVPOStoSolarParkUndergroundCableRoute_metres
    ' End of 33kVPOStoSolarParkUndergroundCableRoute_metres
    
     'START Cable132kVforateedconnection300Cu & cable132kVforaloopedconnection1000Cu
    ' Read the value from cell AA3
    Cable132kVforateedconnection300Cu = Range("AA3").Value
     ' Check the value of cell V3
    If Range("V3").Value = "Tee" Then
    
        ' If sumof132kVPOCtoPOSUndergroundCableRoute not 0,
        If sumof132kVPOCtoPOSUndergroundCableRoute <> 0 Then
        
        ' set the variable value to sumof132kVPOCtoPOSUndergroundCableRoute+60
        Cable132kVforateedconnection300Cu = sumof132kVPOCtoPOSUndergroundCableRoute + 60
        Else
        
        ' if set the variable value to sumof132kVPOCtoPOSUndergroundCableRoute= 0
        Cable132kVforateedconnection300Cu = 0
        End If
        
        Cable132kVforateedconnection300Cu = Cable132kVforateedconnection300Cu * Range("AQ36").Value
        
        Range("AT36").Value = Cable132kVforateedconnection300Cu
        cable132kVforaloopedconnection1000Cu = 0
        Range("AT37").Value = cable132kVforaloopedconnection1000Cu
        
    Else
        ' If sumof132kVPOCtoPOSUndergroundCableRoute not 0,
        If sumof132kVPOCtoPOSUndergroundCableRoute <> 0 Then
        
        ' set the variable value to sumof132kVPOCtoPOSUndergroundCableRoute+60
        cable132kVforaloopedconnection1000Cu = sumof132kVPOCtoPOSUndergroundCableRoute * 2 + 60
        
        Else
        
        ' if set the variable value to sumof132kVPOCtoPOSUndergroundCableRoute= 0
        cable132kVforaloopedconnection1000Cu = 0
 
        End If
        
        cable132kVforaloopedconnection1000Cu = cable132kVforaloopedconnection1000Cu * Range("AQ37").Value
        Range("AT37").Value = cable132kVforaloopedconnection1000Cu
        Cable132kVforateedconnection300Cu = 0
        Range("AT36").Value = Cable132kVforateedconnection300Cu
    End If
    'End of Cable132kVforateedconnection300Cu  & cable132kVforaloopedconnection1000Cu
    
    'start of ProjectManager_DayRate40, SiteManager & SiteSetup, Single132kVcircuitandpilot_fibre trench_Ducted_Agricultural_250,Single132kVcircuitandpilot_fibretrench_Ducted_Verge, Single132kVcircuitandpilot_fibretrench_Ducted_Verge & Single132kVcircuitandpilot_fibre_trench_Ducted_Road_250
    ' Read the value from cell AP16
    ProjectManager_DayRate40 = Range("AP16").Value
    SiteManager_DayRate_80 = Range("AP17").Value
    Single132kVcircuitandpilot_fibre_trench_Ducted_Agricultural_250 = Range("x3").Value
    Single132kVcircuitandpilot_fibre_trench_Ducted_Road_250 = Range("Y3").Value
    Single132kVcircuitandpilot_fibretrench_Ducted_Verge = Range("Z3").Value
    Single132kVcircuitandpilotfibre_trench_Ducted_Footpath_250 = Range("AA3").Value
    
    ' Check the value of cell V3
    If Range("V3").Value = "Tee" Then
        ' If V3 contains "Tee", set the variable value to AP16
        ProjectManager_DayRate40 = ProjectManager_DayRate40
        SiteManager_DayRate_80 = SiteManager_DayRate_80
        SiteSetup = 1 * Range("AQ23").Value
        Single132kVcircuitandpilot_fibre_trench_Ducted_Agricultural_250 = Single132kVcircuitandpilot_fibre_trench_Ducted_Agricultural_250
        Single132kVcircuitandpilot_fibre_trench_Ducted_Road_250 = Single132kVcircuitandpilot_fibre_trench_Ducted_Road_250
        Single132kVcircuitandpilot_fibretrench_Ducted_Verge = Single132kVcircuitandpilot_fibretrench_Ducted_Verge
        Single132kVcircuitandpilotfibre_trench_Ducted_Footpath_250 = Single132kVcircuitandpilotfibre_trench_Ducted_Footpath_250
        Stokboard1m_overlapped275 = sumof132kVPOCtoPOSUndergroundCableRoute * 1.1
        
    Else
        ' If V3 doesn't contain "Tee", set the variable value to AP16 * 2
        ProjectManager_DayRate40 = ProjectManager_DayRate40 * 2
        SiteManager_DayRate_80 = SiteManager_DayRate_80 * 2
        SiteSetup = Range("AQ23").Value * 2
        Single132kVcircuitandpilot_fibre_trench_Ducted_Agricultural_250 = Single132kVcircuitandpilot_fibre_trench_Ducted_Agricultural_250 * 2
        Single132kVcircuitandpilot_fibre_trench_Ducted_Road_250 = Single132kVcircuitandpilot_fibre_trench_Ducted_Road_250 * 2
        Single132kVcircuitandpilot_fibretrench_Ducted_Verge = Single132kVcircuitandpilot_fibretrench_Ducted_Verge * 2
        Single132kVcircuitandpilotfibre_trench_Ducted_Footpath_250 = Single132kVcircuitandpilotfibre_trench_Ducted_Footpath_250 * 2
        Stokboard1m_overlapped275 = sumof132kVPOCtoPOSUndergroundCableRoute * 1.1 * 2
 
                
    End If
    
    ProjectManager_DayRate40 = ProjectManager_DayRate40 * Range("AQ16").Value
    SiteManager_DayRate_80 = SiteManager_DayRate_80 * Range("AQ17").Value
    Single132kVcircuitandpilot_fibre_trench_Ducted_Agricultural_2501 = Single132kVcircuitandpilot_fibre_trench_Ducted_Agricultural_250
    Single132kVcircuitandpilot_fibre_trench_Ducted_Road_2501 = Single132kVcircuitandpilot_fibre_trench_Ducted_Road_250
    Single132kVcircuitandpilot_fibretrench_Ducted_Verge1 = Single132kVcircuitandpilot_fibretrench_Ducted_Verge
    Single132kVcircuitandpilotfibre_trench_Ducted_Footpath_2501 = Single132kVcircuitandpilotfibre_trench_Ducted_Footpath_250
    Single132kVcircuitandpilot_fibre_trench_Ducted_Agricultural_250 = Single132kVcircuitandpilot_fibre_trench_Ducted_Agricultural_250 * Range("AQ32").Value
    Single132kVcircuitandpilot_fibre_trench_Ducted_Road_250 = Single132kVcircuitandpilot_fibre_trench_Ducted_Road_250 * Range("AQ33").Value
    Single132kVcircuitandpilot_fibretrench_Ducted_Verge = Single132kVcircuitandpilot_fibretrench_Ducted_Verge * Range("AQ34").Value
    Single132kVcircuitandpilotfibre_trench_Ducted_Footpath_250 = Single132kVcircuitandpilotfibre_trench_Ducted_Footpath_250 * Range("AQ35").Value
    Stokboard1m_overlapped275 = Stokboard1m_overlapped275 * Range("AQ38").Value
    
    Range("AT16").Value = ProjectManager_DayRate40
    Range("AT17").Value = SiteManager_DayRate_80
    Range("AT23").Value = SiteSetup
    Range("AT32").Value = Single132kVcircuitandpilot_fibre_trench_Ducted_Agricultural_250
    Range("AT33").Value = Single132kVcircuitandpilot_fibre_trench_Ducted_Road_250
    Range("AT34").Value = Single132kVcircuitandpilot_fibretrench_Ducted_Verge
    Range("AT35").Value = Single132kVcircuitandpilotfibre_trench_Ducted_Footpath_250
    Range("AV32").Value = Single132kVcircuitandpilot_fibre_trench_Ducted_Agricultural_2501
    Range("AV33").Value = Single132kVcircuitandpilot_fibre_trench_Ducted_Road_2501
    Range("AV34").Value = Single132kVcircuitandpilot_fibretrench_Ducted_Verge1
    Range("AV35").Value = Single132kVcircuitandpilotfibre_trench_Ducted_Footpath_2501
    Range("AT38").Value = Stokboard1m_overlapped275
    'End of ProjectManager_DayRate40, SiteManager & SiteSetup, Single132kVcircuitandpilot_fibre trench_Ducted_Agricultural_250,Single132kVcircuitandpilot_fibretrench_Ducted_Verge, Single132kVcircuitandpilot_fibretrench_Ducted_Verge & Single132kVcircuitandpilot_fibre_trench_Ducted_Road_250

    
    ' Read the value from cell AP18 x AQ18
    OMManualPackage_ICP_Connection66kV_132kV = Range("AP18").Value * Range("AQ18").Value
    
    Range("AT18").Value = OMManualPackage_ICP_Connection66kV_132kV
    
    ' OMManualsHardcopies3SetsofA4Foldersand1DVDelectroniccopy find value
    OMManualsHardcopies3SetsofA4Foldersand1DVDelectroniccopy = Range("AP19") * Range("AQ19")
    
    Range("AT19").Value = OMManualsHardcopies3SetsofA4Foldersand1DVDelectroniccopy
    
    'AdminAssistant_Day_rate find value
    AdminAssistant_Day_rate = Range("AP20") * Range("AQ20")
    
    Range("AT20").Value = AdminAssistant_Day_rate
    
    Preliminaryworks = ProjectManager_DayRate40 + SiteManager_DayRate_80 + AdminAssistant_Day_rate + OMManualsHardcopies3SetsofA4Foldersand1DVDelectroniccopy + OMManualPackage_ICP_Connection66kV_132kV
        
    Range("AT15").Value = Preliminaryworks
    'End of Preliminaryworks
    
    'Start of ContestableDesignPackage, Excavate_ground_unmade_Agricultural_Excavationdepthsubjecttogroundinvestigation
    Dim Excavate_ground_unmade_Agricultural_Excavationdepthsubjecttogroundinvestigation As Double
    Dim Excavate_ground_unmade_Agricultural_Excavationdepthsubjecttogroundinvestigation1 As Double
    Dim Removesurplusmaterialanddisposeoffsite_subjecttononcontamination_20tperlorryload As Double
    Dim Geotechnicalmembrane650 As Double
    Dim ConcretePlinthforSealingEnd1 As Double
    Dim ConcretePlinthforEHVDisconnector2 As Double
    Dim ConcretePlinthforEHVCircuitBreaker1 As Double
    Dim ConcretePlinthforPostInsulators_CTs_VTs_3 As Double
    Dim LightingColumns2 As Double
    Dim GRPCableTrough25 As Double
    Dim AccessRoad_Track90 As Double
    Dim CompoundMaintenanceStrip140 As Double
    Dim PalisadeFencing90_2point4m As Double
    Dim CastInsituFenceKerb126_400_600mm As Double
    Dim PalisadeDoubleGate2_2ponit4m As Double
    Dim Gravelinfill50 As Double

    ' Check the value of cell U3
    If Range("U3").Value = "33" Then
        ' If V3 contains "33", set the variable value to AP16
        ContestableDesignPackage = 0
        Excavate_ground_unmade_Agricultural_Excavationdepthsubjecttogroundinvestigation = 0
        
    Else
        ' If V3 doesn't contain "Tee", set the variable value to AP16 * 2
        ContestableDesignPackage = 133000
                ' Check the value of cell V3
        If Range("V3").Value = "Tee" Then
        
            Excavate_ground_unmade_Agricultural_Excavationdepthsubjecttogroundinvestigation = Range("ap47").Value
                        
        Else
            Excavate_ground_unmade_Agricultural_Excavationdepthsubjecttogroundinvestigation = Range("ap47").Value * 2
        End If
    End If
    
    Excavate_ground_unmade_Agricultural_Excavationdepthsubjecttogroundinvestigation1 = Excavate_ground_unmade_Agricultural_Excavationdepthsubjecttogroundinvestigation
    Excavate_ground_unmade_Agricultural_Excavationdepthsubjecttogroundinvestigation = Excavate_ground_unmade_Agricultural_Excavationdepthsubjecttogroundinvestigation * Range("aQ47").Value
    
    Range("AT25").Value = ContestableDesignPackage
    Range("AT47").Value = Excavate_ground_unmade_Agricultural_Excavationdepthsubjecttogroundinvestigation
    'End of ContestableDesignPackage, Excavate_ground_unmade_Agricultural_Excavationdepthsubjecttogroundinvestigation
    
    'Start of Terminationkitsatthe132kVsealingends_setof3_1
    Dim v3 As Variant
    Dim w3 As Variant
    Dim u3 As Variant
    
    ' Assign values to v3, w3, and u3
    v3 = Range("V3").Value
    w3 = Range("W3").Value
    u3 = Range("U3").Value
    
    If u3 <> 132 Then
        Terminationkitsatthe132kVsealingends_setof3_1 = 0
    Else
        Select Case v3 & w3
            Case "TeeUG"
                Terminationkitsatthe132kVsealingends_setof3_1 = 2
            Case "TeeOH"
                Terminationkitsatthe132kVsealingends_setof3_1 = 1
            Case "LoopUG"
                Terminationkitsatthe132kVsealingends_setof3_1 = 4
            Case "LoopOH"
                Terminationkitsatthe132kVsealingends_setof3_1 = 2
        End Select
    End If
    Terminationkitsatthe132kVsealingends_setof3_1 = Terminationkitsatthe132kVsealingends_setof3_1 * Range("AQ39").Value
    Range("AT39").Value = Terminationkitsatthe132kVsealingends_setof3_1
    'End of Terminationkitsatthe132kVsealingends_setof3_1
    
    'Start of Fibreopticcableandinstallation270
    Fibreopticcableandinstallation270 = sumof132kVPOCtoPOSUndergroundCableRoute * 1.1 * Range("AQ40").Value
    
    Range("AT40").Value = Fibreopticcableandinstallation270
    'end of Fibreopticcableandinstallation270
    
    'Start of Ducting110mmPilotspermetre250
    Ducting110mmPilotspermetre250 = sumof132kVPOCtoPOSUndergroundCableRoute * Range("AQ41").Value
    
    Range("AT41").Value = Ducting110mmPilotspermetre250
    'End of Ducting110mmPilotspermetre250
    
    'start of Tiletape150mmX250mWPDspec1
    Tiletape150mmX250mWPDspec1 = WorksheetFunction.Quotient(Single132kVcircuitandpilot_fibre_trench_Ducted_Agricultural_2501 + Single132kVcircuitandpilot_fibre_trench_Ducted_Road_2501 + Single132kVcircuitandpilot_fibretrench_Ducted_Verge1 + Single132kVcircuitandpilotfibre_trench_Ducted_Footpath_2501, Range("AP42").Value) * Range("AQ42").Value
    
    Range("AT42").Value = Tiletape150mmX250mWPDspec1
    ' end of Tiletape150mmX250mWPDspec1
    
    'start of CableInstallationTeam_4men_1x_Supervisorand3xlabourers_DayRate WorksheetFunction.RoundUp((sumof132kVPOCtoPOSUndergroundCableRoute / Range("AP43").Value), 0) * 2 * Range("AQ43").Value
    CableInstallationTeam_4men_1x_Supervisorand3xlabourers_DayRate = WorksheetFunction.RoundUp((Single132kVcircuitandpilot_fibre_trench_Ducted_Agricultural_2501 + Single132kVcircuitandpilot_fibre_trench_Ducted_Road_2501 + Single132kVcircuitandpilot_fibretrench_Ducted_Verge1 + Single132kVcircuitandpilotfibre_trench_Ducted_Footpath_2501) / Range("AP43").Value, 0) * 2 * Range("AQ43").Value
    Range("AT43").Value = CableInstallationTeam_4men_1x_Supervisorand3xlabourers_DayRate
    'End of CableInstallationTeam_4men_1x_Supervisorand3xlabourers_DayRate
    
    'start of JointBay_132kVsinglecircuitandpilot_fibre_Agricultural, JointBay_132kVsinglecircuitandpilot_fibre_Road, JointBay_132kVsinglecircuitandpilot_fibre_verge & JointBayatPOC_132kVsinglecircuitandpilo_fibre_Ducted_Footpath
    JointBay_132kVsinglecircuitandpilot_fibre_Agricultural = WorksheetFunction.Quotient(Single132kVcircuitandpilot_fibre_trench_Ducted_Agricultural_2501, Range("AP28").Value) * 5 * Range("AQ28").Value
    JointBay_132kVsinglecircuitandpilot_fibre_Road = (WorksheetFunction.Quotient(Single132kVcircuitandpilot_fibre_trench_Ducted_Road_2501, Range("AP29").Value) + 1) * 5 * Range("AQ29").Value
    JointBay_132kVsinglecircuitandpilot_fibre_verge = WorksheetFunction.Quotient(Single132kVcircuitandpilot_fibretrench_Ducted_Verge1, Range("AP30").Value) * 5 * Range("AQ30").Value
    JointBayatPOC_132kVsinglecircuitandpilo_fibre_Ducted_Footpath = WorksheetFunction.Quotient(Single132kVcircuitandpilotfibre_trench_Ducted_Footpath_2501, Range("AP31").Value) * 5 * Range("AQ31").Value
    JointingTeam_1xJointer1xMate_DayRate4 = Range("AQ44").Value * Range("AP44").Value * (WorksheetFunction.Quotient(Single132kVcircuitandpilot_fibre_trench_Ducted_Agricultural_2501, Range("AP28").Value) + (WorksheetFunction.Quotient(Single132kVcircuitandpilot_fibre_trench_Ducted_Road_2501, Range("AP29").Value) + 1) + WorksheetFunction.Quotient(Single132kVcircuitandpilot_fibretrench_Ducted_Verge1, Range("AP30").Value) + WorksheetFunction.Quotient(Single132kVcircuitandpilotfibre_trench_Ducted_Footpath_2501, Range("AP31").Value))
    
    Range("AV28").Value = JointBay_132kVsinglecircuitandpilot_fibre_Agricultural
    Range("AV29").Value = JointBay_132kVsinglecircuitandpilot_fibre_Road
    Range("AV30").Value = JointBay_132kVsinglecircuitandpilot_fibre_verge
    Range("AV31").Value = JointBayatPOC_132kVsinglecircuitandpilo_fibre_Ducted_Footpath
    Range("At44").Value = JointingTeam_1xJointer1xMate_DayRate4
    'End of JointBay_132kVsinglecircuitandpilot_fibre_Agricultural, JointBay_132kVsinglecircuitandpilot_fibre_Road, JointBay_132kVsinglecircuitandpilot_fibre_verge & JointBayatPOC_132kVsinglecircuitandpilo_fibre_Ducted_Footpath
    
    'start of CableRoute132_66kV
    CableRoute132_66kV = JointBay_132kVsinglecircuitandpilot_fibre_Agricultural + JointBay_132kVsinglecircuitandpilot_fibre_Road + JointBay_132kVsinglecircuitandpilot_fibre_verge + JointBayatPOC_132kVsinglecircuitandpilo_fibre_Ducted_Footpath + Single132kVcircuitandpilot_fibre_trench_Ducted_Agricultural_250 + Single132kVcircuitandpilot_fibre_trench_Ducted_Road_250 + Single132kVcircuitandpilot_fibretrench_Ducted_Verge + Single132kVcircuitandpilotfibre_trench_Ducted_Footpath_250 + Cable132kVforateedconnection300Cu + cable132kVforaloopedconnection1000Cu + Stokboard1m_overlapped275 + Terminationkitsatthe132kVsealingends_setof3_1 + Fibreopticcableandinstallation270 + Ducting110mmPilotspermetre250 + Tiletape150mmX250mWPDspec1 + CableInstallationTeam_4men_1x_Supervisorand3xlabourers_DayRate + JointingTeam_1xJointer1xMate_DayRate4
    Range("AT27").Value = CableRoute132_66kV
    'End of CableRoute132_66kV
    
    'start of Removesurplusmaterialanddisposeoffsite_subjecttononcontamination_20tperlorryload
    Removesurplusmaterialanddisposeoffsite_subjecttononcontamination_20tperlorryload = WorksheetFunction.Quotient(Excavate_ground_unmade_Agricultural_Excavationdepthsubjecttogroundinvestigation1, Range("ap48").Value) * Range("aQ48").Value
    Range("AT48").Value = Removesurplusmaterialanddisposeoffsite_subjecttononcontamination_20tperlorryload
    'End of Removesurplusmaterialanddisposeoffsite_subjecttononcontamination_20tperlorryload
End Sub
```

I have some inputs that I get from row 3 (specifically V3:AE3) and when the code has done what it is going to do for row 3 I want it to do it for row 4 and so on until the v column is empty. I also want to make it so that if any of the v to AE column is updated it repeats the calculation for that specific row that was updated.

I have made this but am struggling on how i would implement it to the above code. I know I have to change the ("v3") to ("V" & i) but further than that I am unsure how i merge the two. If anyone has any ideas on how to help me here that would be greatly appreciated.

sorry if this isn't very good or the format that is normal very up for being educated on how things should be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disclaimer: I haven't read your entire code because it is very long. It seems like what you want is to pass a variable from one sub to another. There are plenty of tutorials around that will be more detailed than this, and it might be good to practice on a simpler example before replacing your code. In your example:

Change the name of `Sub Preliminaryworks()` to `Sub Preliminaryworks(i As Long)`. Now when you call the macro, you have to give it a value to use for `i`. `i` will represent the row number you want to work on.

In `Preliminaryworks`, change anything that refers to row 3, to refer to row `i`. For example change `Range("V3").Value` to `Range("V" & i).Value`. Now instead of working on row 3, it will work on whatever row you give it.

In `Private Sub GPS(ByVal Target As Range)`, change `Preliminaryworks` to `Preliminaryworks(i)`. Now whatever row is being checked in `GPS`, that row number will be passed to `Preliminaryworks`, and `Preliminaryworks` will work on that row.

Comment: So I did as you said (thank you again for your help) and I have the code in sheet 2. The GPS sub is after the sub Preliminaryworks and every time I click the run the macros window pops up asking me to name a new sub and I am not sure why?

Comment: Now that Preliminaryworks needs to be given a value for `i`, you can't just click to run it, because it doesn't know what value to use for `i`. The standard approach would be to create a new sub, say `Sub run_Preliminaryworks()` with just one line of code `Call Preliminaryworks(3)` or whatever value you want to use for `i`.

Comment: I see brilliant thank you again. I have done this with a few amendments and it works just as I would expect!